# não me esta a verificar se um botão esta checked ou nao

Tags: jquery

```js
if (document.getElementById("circular_select").checked === true) {
  piechart();
}
if (document.getElementById("barras_select").checked === true) {
  alert("You have selected Option 1");
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group custom-btn-group  " data-toggle="buttons" >
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <img src="img/3d-pie-chart-icon.png" alt=""/>
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="feature" value="opt0"  id="circular_select" checked="checked"    />

  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default ">
    <img src="img/SEO-icon.png" alt=""/>
    <input type="radio" class="form-control"  name="feature" value="opt1" id="barras_select"  />
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você colocar um `alert()` no primeiro if ele será disparado, deve haver algo errado com a sua função piechart();

Exemplo:

```js
if (document.getElementById("circular_select").checked === true) {
  alert('check 1');
}
if (document.getElementById("barras_select").checked === true) {
  alert('check 2');
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group custom-btn-group  " data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <img src="img/3d-pie-chart-icon.png" alt="" />
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="feature" value="opt0" id="circular_select" checked="checked" />
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default ">
    <img src="img/SEO-icon.png" alt="" />
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="feature" value="opt1" id="barras_select" />
  </label>
</div>
```